# Git error, command git fetch Fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git in visual studio code

Tags: git, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I have to start with Flutter for web and downloaded DART sdk as well as Visual studio code and i have installed Flutter plugin is VS code but its showing error

Git error, command git fetch

Fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Process finished with exit code 69

I have set path of git in Intellij as well as set desktop environment in windows but there too(Intellij), same error is coming

Ps: I am new to this all please suggest me the solution in detail

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your working copy is not a cloned one. Clone the SDK via the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk.git
```

Comment: where should i do this? in project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Move into the project folder. Then initialize a local repository by using The `git init` command. This will create a .git folder that allows you to use git commands